# How do I catch a VK_TAB key in my TEdit control and not let it lose the focus?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, keypress

In my TEdit field I have text in the form `<number1>..<number2>`.

My idea is:

When a user enters the control using <kbd>TAB</kbd> from another control, `number1` gets selected.

When my TEdit control has a focus and user presses <kbd>TAB</kbd> again, I want the `number2` to get selected and `number1` to be deselected.

And if current caret position is at the place where number2 is, pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> should act normal and move the focus to the next control on the form.

I have 2 problems.

1. I cannot catch the tab key press when the Edit field is active already. I can only catch it when this control is being entered/focused.
2. I don't know if there is a key similar to #0 so I could turn the key into NoOP.

Any ideas, how to do it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are better to write your own TEdit descendant that processes WM_GETDLGCODE message. The general idea is:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TMyEdit = class(TEdit)
    procedure WMGetDlgCode(var Message: TWMGetDlgCode); message WM_GETDLGCODE;
  end;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Edit2: TEdit;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FMyEdit: TMyEdit;
    FDone: Boolean;
    procedure MyEditEnter(Sender: TObject);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TMyEdit }

procedure TMyEdit.WMGetDlgCode(var Message: TWMGetDlgCode);
begin
  inherited;
  Message.Result:= Message.Result or DLGC_WANTTAB;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FMyEdit:= TMyEdit.Create(Self);
  FMyEdit.Left:= 40;
  FMyEdit.Top:= 40;
  FMyEdit.Parent:= Self;
  FMyEdit.Text:= '45..90';
  FMyEdit.OnEnter:= MyEditEnter;
  KeyPreview:= True;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if (Key = #9) and (ActiveControl = FMyEdit) then begin
    if FDone then begin
      Perform(CM_DialogKey, VK_TAB, 0);
    end
    else begin
      FMyEdit.SelStart:= 4;
      FMyEdit.SelLength:= 2;
    end;
    FDone:= not FDone;
    Key:= #0;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.MyEditEnter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FDone:= False;
  FMyEdit.SelStart:= 0;
  FMyEdit.SelLength:= 2;
end;

end.
```

**Updated**: The same idea without making a TEdit descendant class:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    procedure Edit2Enter(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FDone: Boolean;
    FOldWndProc: TWndMethod;
    procedure Edit2WindowProc(var Message: TMessage);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Edit2Enter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FDone:= False;
  Edit2.SelStart:= 0;
  Edit2.SelLength:= 2;
end;

procedure TForm1.Edit2WindowProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  if Message.Msg = WM_GETDLGCODE then
    Message.Result:= Message.Result or DLGC_WANTTAB
  else
    if Assigned(FOldWndProc) then FOldWndProc(Message);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  KeyPreview:= True;
  Edit2.Text:= '45..90';
  FOldWndProc:= Edit2.WindowProc;
  Edit2.WindowProc:= Edit2WindowProc;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if (Key = #9) and (ActiveControl = Edit2) then begin
    if FDone then begin
      Perform(CM_DialogKey, VK_TAB, 0);
    end
    else begin
      Edit2.SelStart:= 4;
      Edit2.SelLength:= 2;
    end;
    FDone:= not FDone;
    Key:= #0;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Handling `wm_GetDlgCode` is definitely the way to go. You don't *have* to make a descendant class, though. You can set any control's `WndProc` property to catch whatever messages you want.

Answer (score 0):

1. you can catch a Tab press on a KeyDown event. (Happens before the KeyPress Event)
2. in a KeyDown event you can set the Key to #0

Oh and in a Key Press event you can set the Key to 0

**EDIT**
    The following is a call stack capturing a KeyDown event for a TAB key

```
Form1.TForm1.GetTab((45061, 9, 0, 983041, 0))
:0101f444 TForm1.GetTab
:004dca20 TWinControl.WndProc + $500
:004ef754 TCustomForm.WndProc + $558
:004d86b3 TControl.Perform + $27
:004ded6a TWinControl.CNKeyDown + $D6
:004dca20 TWinControl.WndProc + $500
:004dc147 TWinControl.MainWndProc + $2F
:004306ea StdWndProc + $16
:7e418734 USER32.GetDC + 0x6d
:7e418816 ; C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll
:7e41b4c0 ; C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll
:7e41b50c ; C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll
:7c90eae3 ntdll.KiUserCallbackDispatcher + 0x13
:7e42f3cc USER32.SendMessageA + 0x49
```

As you can see it doesn go through KeyDown as normal keys do but instead calls `BroadCast` to send the message out....

So you'll need a message catcher

```
Procedure GetTab( var Message: TCMDialogkey ); message CM_DIALOGKEY;
```

to catch it.

Comment: KeyPress event requires Key: Char. However, TAB key is a special key and as far as i know it cannot be recognized in this method.
 the OnKeyDown and OnKeyUp event require Key: Word. These methods do recognize the TAB key becauset here is "VK_TAB". Problem with this is, on key down event does not fire up at all while Edit control is active. OnKeyUp, is fired only in the case when my Edit control -receives- the focus. I need to capture the TAb key press while the Edit control -already has the focus-

Comment: Im pretty sure #9 is a the char equivilent to VK_Tab

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at TJvIPAddress in [JvComCtrls](http://www.koders.com/delphi/fidE8DC864B170142BE714B0C38DAF63B935CC13532.aspx?s=paint.pas). I guess searching for TabThroughFields and VK_TAB should put you on track.