# How to process Tab key by TCustomControl descendant?

Tags: delphi, keyboard, onkeydown, onkeypress

I have a descendant of TCustomControl and want to process Tab key when user press it. But when I press Tab key the focused control on the form just changed. And OnKeyDown and OnKeyPress events didn't fire. How to solve the problem?

Comment: Handle the `CM_DIALOGKEY` message. Look for instance at [`this question`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10470053/960757).

Comment: But we should use CM_DIALOGKEY message on TForm. May fix the issue on component (descendant of TCustomControl) level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the component handle the `WM_GETDLGCODE` message so it can return the `DLGC_WANTTAB` flag.  See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363456/) for an example.